# Replace theme header image with featured image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, replace, themes

i'm using the Casper theme on Wordpress. It displays a header image across the whole site, however i'd like it to display the featured image when viewing a post.

I've found the code below in header.php

```
<header id="masthead" role="banner" class="site-head site-header" <?php if(get_header_image() ) : ?>style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);"<?php endif ?>>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&  ($image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' ) ) && $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
       echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
   elseif ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
       <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ram. I managed to fix it by installing a plugin called 'Custom Header Extended'. I think your solution is better if I would like to change theme in the future.